# Joining other results from same table mysql knex

Tags: mysql, join, outer-join, knex.js

I would like to get other `user_id`s from the same table that match the `event_id`s. I've tried with a sub-query and a `this.on` function in a leftJoin and outerLeftJoin. Can't get around the 'not unique table/alias' error with the code below.

```
knex('user_2_event')
            .select(
                'event.*',
                'user_2_event.user_id as main_user_id'
            )
            .where('user_2_event.user_id',17)
            .join('event', 'event.event_id', 'user_2_event.event_id')
            .leftOuterJoin('user_2_event', function(){
                this.on('user_2_event.event_id', '=', 'event.event_id') 
            })
```

or this instead of the above leftOuterJoin, which produces an 'error with my syntax'.

```
            .join(
                knex('user_2_event')
                .select('user_2_event.user_id as other_user')
                .where('user_2_event.event', '=','event.event_id')
            )
```

Comment: Hi. "other user_ids from the same table that match the event_ids" is not clear. Use enough sentences & phrases to clearly say what you mean. Please read & act on [mcve]. Finding minima code that exhibits your problem involves first reducing to maximal code without a problem--look at the additional code that gets you to the MCVE. Which shoud include your exact error message. Also--please read [ask] & the downvote arrow mouseover text. Here, google your error messages with & without your particular strings/names. Read the manual on every operator.

Comment: Was it really that difficult to get at where the issue might lie in my approach? Obviously my inexperience means I'll be phrasing things a bit poorly. If I was more experienced then I would probably know the basics. Forums and the internet and communication exists to allow for more efficient exchange of information, so no reinventing of the wheel or 'reading the manual on everything' is necessary when 3min on one person's part could save, hmm, years on another's. Luckily, somebody I know suggested using aliases for the tables, which I didn't know was possible. Maybe you could have said, but no

Comment: I simply didn't happen to see the problem. Why should I? 14 others didn't either. Whereas a compilier is a program designed to find such problems. Bur you didn't give code you already have that is needed to run one. You didn't give your compiler's error message that you already have. I did, however, nevertheless give you advice to help you get more help. Yet you complain. Why should people spend their time when you are not willing to & are wasting theirs? (Rhetorical.) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/3404097

Comment: PS If you edit your question according to my comments & links then people might upvote it. Also if you accept your answer when you can it tells others you found a solution. And if you edit it to improve it to clearly explain to googlers finding your question the ideas behind "use aliases" then your answer might get upvotes too.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I might get back to it, at the minute marching ahead with priorities. I had a look and it might take me a bit to understand what it is exactly that's required of me. I really think the example, especially compared to the original post, makes it clear enough what the change is. Up-votes, down-votes, I don't know, it's an obsession. There's a trigger-happy snobbery with those who down-vote (not saying you per se, but it's the feel of SO, and not just in my view), while those looking for a solution actually take a moment to see if the question and solution are relevant.

Comment: You could up-vote it as the solution ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching in various ways for guidance on getting at data in separate ways on the same table (however one expresses that in technical terms), it was suggested to me to use aliases on the same table. Voila, quick and easy without worrying about join functions and sub-queries.

```
knex('user_2_event as e1')
            .select(
                'event.*',
                'e1.user_id as user_id',
                'e2.user_id as other_id'
            )
            .where('e1.user_id',17)
            .join('event', 'event.event_id', 'e1.event_id')
            .leftJoin('user_2_event as e2', 'e2.event_id', 'event.event_id')
```